# Extract data for a particular time-interval from a set of continous readings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for alternative methods to extracting data, wind speed to be precise, for a particular month in a particular year.
I have readings at 10-minute intervals from 2004 to 2019.

I'd like to, for example, extract all values for say February 2008.

This is what it looks like

```
Timestamp           Speed (m/s)
01.01.2004 00:00    0
01.01.2004 00:10    8,11
01.01.2004 00:20    8,09
01.01.2004 00:30    8,27
```

What I currently do is, use a combination of MATCH, ADDRESS and INDIRECT to get at the Timestamps of the first and last reading for each month.

**I'd then use these in an array function**

WINDATEN - Is the sheet with all the readings

```
2008             Start                     End
                 01.02.2008 00:00          29.02.2008 23:50
=MATCH()         214850                    219025
=ADDRESS()      'WINDATEN'!$B$214850       'WINDATEN'!$B$219025 
=INDIRECT()      21,36                      21.87
```

I'd like to know if there are, perhaps, more elegant ways to achieve what I want? Instead of the whole ADDRESS and INDIRECT business.

Comment: `INDEX(MATCH(…` would get you those values, without the issue of being volatile (which can be a problem with `INDIRECT` depending on the complexity of your worksheet).  `VLOOKUP` can also work if your timestamps are in the leftmost column of your data.

Comment: Also, depending on what you want to do with this data, returning the `ADDRESS` of the location may be unnecessary.  For example, to obtain a monthly average, you could merely use `AVERAGEIFS`.  To create a histogram, you could probably just use filters, maybe with a Pivot Chart.  Etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton, It's beyond me why I did not think of using a simple INDEX MATCH thingy!, works with both the array based FREQUENCY formula as well as with the COUNTIFS ( which i use to calculate the frequency with)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you wanted to get the average wind speed for a range of times in a particular day. You could still use Match to get the first and last rows, but then use the following method to get Index to produce an array of values:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: First of, thanks. I however, don't need the average the average speeds, just an alternate method to get the "End points" or the first and last rows.
I'm a bit of an Excel novice. I'd like use them them, say in the FREQUENCY() formula to generate a Histogram or something similar :)

I'm a bit of an Excel novice, I'm keen on exploring different options

Comment: I've realised that I went all round the houses anyway to get an array between two timestamps - have replaced the original formula. Yes, as @Ron Rosenfeld said, it is much easier with Index/match, Vlookup or even old-school Lookup. I don't quite understand how you would use the start and end points in a histogram though...maybe there is another question trying to get out?

Comment: I use the start and end points to extract an array containing about 4000 values. I then use COUNTIFS to calculate the frequency of these values corresponding to a Bin size of 0,5 m/s as a percentage of the total. So Bins on the X axis and Frequency on the Y